# 301 redirect when using SailsJs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Situation: Upgrading an old site that was basic HTML to use SailsJS. Old site has .html extensions and is ranked well in search engines for these results. As such I would like to route all incoming requests from their old URLs (.html extension) to their new results generated via sails (no extension).

The best approach seems to be a 301 redirect but I am unsure as the best practices to implement this using a SailsJS based server.

www.blah.com/blah2.xml  => www.blah.com/blah2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Sails [custom routes](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html).

---

Copy your view file in the `views` folder. Replace its extension by `ejs`.

You can now add each route you want to use in your `config/routes.js` file like:

```
module.exports = {

    'GET /blah2.html': { view: 'blah2' },
    ...

};
```

Answer (score 3):

For SEO purposes you must handle this with HTTP status codes also. You should use custom routes (config/routes.js) and make a controller with this code:

```
module.exports = {
  // this is you action name
  redirect: function(req, res) {
    res.status(301);
    return res.view('blah2');
  }
}
```

You should also create the view in your views folder and set the route to go through your controller.

Comment: Internal parser is happy now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the redirect() function in sails. Because in terms of SEO, a 301 (permanent) redirect is the best practice.

Here you have an example how to use it inside your config/**routes.js** file:

```
'/blah2.xml': (req,res)=>{ return res.redirect(301,'/blah2') },
```

For more information refer to the sails.js documentation:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-redirect